# how can i get jobid's of all yarn jobs launched by oozie?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I want to show logs of all yarn jobs spawned by oozie workflow for pig action.How can I get the jobid's for all child jobs launched by oozie launcher.one method is to parse logs of the launcher but it may contains repeated jobid's. Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can search for the Child job ID from the Oozie DB, it depends on which Oozie DB you are using, that could be MySQL/postgre/Oracle.

in the DB, under oozie database, there will be tables available like "wf_actions" and "wf_jobs" these will be containing the Oozie Child Job instances. Similarly, for Oozie Parent Jobs the tables need to check like "coord_jobs" and "coord_actions".

inside wf_jobs, you will get all the ID's in Runing state, Killed state, Suspend state.
Search for ID's with required states.

Hope these will help to get your query done.